# How to execute JS code on MongoDB using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

How can I execute a small piece of JS code on MongoDB using PHP and preferably using the laravel-mongodb driver, but that is not a hard requirement.

```
var size = 0;
db.mycollection.find( { project_id: 151 } ).forEach(function(obj) {
    var curr = Object.bsonsize(obj); 
    size = size + curr;
})
print(size);
```

It does not matter if this needs to be transformed to a stored function, as long as it is able to run on a shared MongoDB and the project ID (in this case 151) is not fixed. And if somebody knows a better function or solution thats also OK with me, as long as I can calculate the size of all objects for a given project_id.

Any toughts on the matter?

Comment: First Google result: http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php

Comment: I do feel a bit stupid right now. Can you help me with the error it returns: `Non-static method MongoDB::execute() cannot be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`?

Comment: That is just the annotation on the documentation, take a look at the examples to find out how to actually call it

Comment: yeah I saw, thanks for the help and sorry for jumping the gun, I'll dive into it (at this point I get an unauthorized error but I guess that is my mistake since I can run it in the shell :). Still thanks again.

Comment: All JS ran externally must run on a User with full admin rights, aka the user you put into your mongoclient connection must have complete control over your database

Comment: Oh damn it is a shared server so I don't have full admin rights (I expect). What if I change the code with a cronjob and instead of printing the size, inserting it `db.size.insert( { size: size } );`. Would that be possible? And would it than be possible to provide the project_id as a parameter or do I have to get all distinct project_id's in the collection and loop over them using a foreach?

Comment: If this is a shared envo you could use PHPs own function in a cronjob: http://php.net/manual/en/function.bson-encode.php with a strlen to give you the byte size of a BSON document

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP-PECL-mongodb >=1.0.0 with a version of mongoDB <=4.0, you can still work with the [`eval` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/eval/) :

It is deprecated since mongoDB 3.0 and I dont' know if a future version will allow an alternative.

The [`MongoDB\Driver\Manager::executeCommand()` method](https://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.executecommand.php) will help you for executing the `eval` command.

With your example :

```
$jscode = new \MongoDB\BSON\Javascript(<<<'NOWDOC'
var size = 0;
db.mycollection.find( { project_id: 151 } ).forEach(function(obj) {
    var curr = Object.bsonsize(obj); 
    size = size + curr;
})
return size;
NOWDOC
);
```

Note that the `print` function does not write any output during evaluation, I return the value with  `return` instead.

The execution could be :

```
$manager = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager($uri, $uriOptions, $driverOptions);
$result = $manager->executeCommand('dbname', new \MongoDB\Driver\Command(['eval' => $jscode]))->toArray();

var_dump($result[0]["retval"]); // returned size (int)
var_dump($result[0]['ok']); // 1 (double)
```

NB: for executing JS, you must have the good rights (admin role)